# ASP.NET Field Validation Control works in IE7 but not Chrome of Firefox

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net

ASP.NET Field Validation Control work in IE7 but not Chrome or Firefox.(Framework 1.1)

I have a SSN textbox and it has a field validation control. If user does not put a SSN and click on submit button IE 7 correctly shows "please input SSN". Chrome or FireFox do nothing. It is like validation control is ignored.

Any feedback appreciated.

Comment: You could look at jquery validation? also, IE 7 is slightly out of date, I'm frustrated working with IE 8 in work...

Comment: wow! something works in ie7 but not in chrome and firefox. what's the validation expression you using for ssn?